How to make a circle inside other circles white and fat?
I have a problem, to change the color of a single circle in my plotly graph. I want to color the third ring white and make it fat and also the 7th ring, to show separate layers.
I have tried a lot, like line_color and so on, but it did not affect the ring itself, but the piece of the cake.
I will give you an example code, where I need this to be implemented:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Daten für das Beispiel (Mittelwerte aus der eingangs erwähnten Tabelle)
dimensionen = [
    'Daten/Technologie', 'Organisation und Prozesse', 'Strategie und Governance',
    'Mindset und Kultur', 'Umsetzbarkeit und Zusammenarbeit', 'Externe Marktteilnehmer'
]

# Mittelwerte der Skalen pro Dimension (aus der Tabelle)
mittelwerte = {
    'Daten/Technologie': 6, 'Organisation und Prozesse': 5, 'Strategie und Governance': 7,
    'Mindset und Kultur': 8, 'Umsetzbarkeit und Zusammenarbeit': 3, 'Externe Marktteilnehmer': 2
}

# Viridis colormap für die Farbauswahl
viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 12)
colors = [mcolors.to_hex(viridis(i)) for i in range(viridis.N)]

# Funktion zur Erstellung des erweiterten Donut-Radars
def create_extended_donut_radar(dimensionen, mittelwerte):
    num_dimensionen = len(dimensionen)
    num_scales = 11  # 11 Skalen von 0 bis 10

    fig = go.Figure()

    for idx, dim_name in enumerate(dimensionen):
        mittelwert = mittelwerte[dim_name]

        # Bar für jede Skala hinzufügen
        for scale in range(num_scales):
            inner_radius = scale * 0.09 + 0.05  # Adjusted for equal spacing
            outer_radius = inner_radius + 0.09  # Adjusted for equal spacing

            if scale == 0:
                color = 'white'
            elif scale <= mittelwert:
                color = colors[scale]
            else:
                color = 'lightgrey'
                
                

            fig.add_trace(go.Barpolar(
                r=[inner_radius, outer_radius],
                theta=[(360 / num_dimensionen) * idx] ,
                width=[(360 / num_dimensionen) - 1],
                marker_color=color,
                marker_line_color='black',
                marker_line_width=2,
                opacity=0.7
            ))

    # Layout anpassen
    fig.update_layout(
        title='',
        title_font_size=24,
        title_x=0.5,
        polar=dict(
            radialaxis=dict(visible=False),
            angularaxis=dict(visible=False)
        ),
        showlegend=False
    )

    # Plotly Diagramm im Standard-Browser anzeigen
    fig.show(renderer='browser')
    





# Donut-Radar erstellen
create_extended_donut_radar(dimensionen, mittelwerte)

Here a png, where i did a red marker for what I want to be white and fat:

"to change the color of a single circle in my plotly graph"... " I want to color the third ring white and make it fat and also the 7th ring" - are you trying to change the color(s) of one or two circles? Also how are you counting; from the center towards the circumference or from the circumference towards the center?

And by "making it fat" are you referring to the border width being thicker or the circle getting bigger?

I need the third circle from the centre towards the circumference to appear white (just the line of the circle and not the plain). With getting thicker i mean, that the line that is white should appear thicker than the other circle lines.

Do either of these meet your requirements: [A], [B] ?

see my edited answer
